# How to update a particular field in mongodb using a combination of other two fields?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

If the document structure is like A, B and C are fields. I want to update the C (third field) using a combination of A and B (first two fields).

[Open the image for structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swfga.png)

From the picture above, this is a single entry. I want to update the "quantity" based on the combination of "productId" and "userId".

Comment: What do you mean by "...based on the combination of "productId" and "userId"", you mean mathematical combination, like average?

Comment: Can you show us a sample document, what it should be after update, and any query you've tried?

Comment: You can filter for the two columns, and change the value with $set of the third one.

Comment: it seems to me that you want to use populate, since each `productId` and `userId` are document ids.